# Observe metadata operations in RabbitMQ

Tags: messaging, rabbitmq, amqp

I want to send a message whenever RabbitMQ creates or deletes a queue, exchange or binding. Is this feasible from a client API? What about as a plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcelo, would you mind asking this question on the rabbitmq-discuss list please?  Some functionality of this type is possible, but I am not sure what is currently supported and what still needs to be done.

Cheers

alexis

Comment: I've posted the question, as requested.